# UDP Socket Programming - Receive Speed

Tags: .net, networking, packets

I'm making a small Console Application which is a game with multiplayer.

The multiplayer works with UDP, and I have a concern regarding receive speed.

Here's the current receive code:

```
    void Receive()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Started");
        while (true)
        {
            byte[] msg = new byte[1024];
            client.Receive(msg);
            string message = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(msg);
            if (...) ...
            if (...) ...
            if (...) ...
        }
    }
```

And so on with a few checks (right after a packet is received these checks are being done).

So my question is - while it's decent for a Console Application, what about handling hundreds or thousands of clients?

When handling a big number of clients, the receive and respond speed is very important.

And these checks, of course, slow down the receive process.

Is there a way to make the receive process faster, so the server will be able to handle even hundreds of clients concurrently?

And if there's a way, should it be done in the client as well?

Comment: Are there any ordering requirements between separate packets?

Comment: No. The packet is received, then checked through the if statements to determine the type. I have thought on using a separate thread for treating packets but I think that it just might be a mess, and I'm currently looking for a good way to treat packets without messing up with Receive speed.

Comment: I don;t know the size of your packets, or how many rules you apply when received. But as a benchmark, looking at something like a network router.... those guys handle "millions" of packets, all dissected and pulled apart for source and destination headers, firewall , routing rules get applied (easily anything from 10 to a lot more rules) included in the speed spec... and they run on silly small processors

Comment: I know, but if a server receives 1000 packets per second, for example, then it means speed is top priority. 4-5 IF statements slow down the Receive method, and when the if statements are being checked, the server couldn't receive a thing. Even if the checks are being done for less than a second, it still is critical when handling thousands of clients. So should I just make the IF statements on a separate thread?

Comment: I think you are underestimating the power of computing... Unless you are doing some REALLY long stuff... first bench test it and see how it performs. If you are indeed doing some time consuming operations, like accessing a db, then I would vote for sending it off in a new thread to allow the receive buffer to continue receiving.

Comment: I would instead consider using `BeginReceive` and `EndReceive`. Inside your callback method, you would call `EndReceive` for the request that's just completed, then call `BeginReceive` to start the next receive, before you start doing any actual data checks on the packet that you're just received. Behind the scenes, threads are being used, but you don't have to write that bit of code.

Comment: @BlueRay010 when you watch a mpeg2 HD film from network (assuming multicast) your computer gets ~1000 packets per second, process them and then shows the movie. Is that speed is enough?

Comment: OK, Thank you both. I'll try both suggestions.